# Compiling Hello World on Angström (Beagleboard)

Tags: gcc, g++, arm

I am running Angström on a Beagleboard. I installed gcc and g++ using the command:
    opkg install gcc g++

Now, when I am trying to compile the simplest c and c++ hello world programs, I get the error messages:

```
g++: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
```

What do you think is missing?

Comment: Maybe someone else will find this list of needed packages useful: http://boards.openpandora.org/topic/14991-solved-gcc-native-angstrom-install/ I' particularly, was missing `gcc-symlinks`, `libc6-dev` and `cpp-symlinks`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` is part of the `binutils` package, so perhaps you need to install that.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply. yes, [binutils] was missing.